# Schemeless URLS and misbehaving crwalers

Tags: nginx

I am using schemeless urls for loading few external libraries.

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery.....`

The problem i am facing is that few crawlers are treating them as relative urls

`www.mydomain.com//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery.....`

How can i handle such links for crawlers.

I am using Nginx server but i am fairly new to Nginx.

is some kind of rewrite possible?

Comment: Why not just ignore them?

Comment: as of now my server is responding with 404. I wish to redirect instead.

Comment: What for? Crawlers will not execute this js anyway. Also, it's really bad designed crawlers and there is no point to care about them.

Comment: hmmm. you mean to say i can safely ignore such crawlers. My problem is with baidu. I dont really have much traffic with them but i just wanted to do it for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is actually valid, it's the crawler's fault for not handling this case while crawling, I would just ignore it.

Also the 404 response is also valid from your server, because the crawler is requesting `www.example.com//ajax.googleapis.com/..` which really doesn't exist.